# Bookmap Invalid Data While Decoding

Tags: trading, .net-4.8

I am receiving this error when I launch bookmap trading software. I did install the last recommended version of Netframework 2019. Bookmap was working fine until today, I haven't change anything besides installing few video editing softwares. Please a solution

I tried uninstalling the program using Revo Uninstaller.  THen I  installed bookmap again. I tried to update my netframe work but it says that it's already updated.